# Does Phonegap Storage API creates a native app database?

Tags: javascript, cordova, lawnchair

I just want to confirm. When using Phonegap Storage API. Does it actually creates / write a native SQL database?

Because I probably create a native code C++ / Java to access it and do some stuff there. :)

Thanks.